# dleyna renderer service

Tags: 16.04, services

Hi all as you can see in the image below the dleyna renderer service is using 25% of my cpu power (1 core) does anyone know what it is doing and weather it is needed on the system or not (If further details are needed please ask and I will try to provide them)
[image]

Comment: It is part of an audio/video streaming package.  It may have been installed by a media player package. If you do `ps aux | grep 3997` you may find its parent process, and so on. If you want to know why it was installed, do `sudo apt install aptitude` and do `aptitude why dleyna-renderer`.

Comment: @Jos thanks it is a dependency of gnome photos and only seems to use up the cpu after gnome photos is closed any ideas why

Comment: It's a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dleyna-renderer/+bug/1590343).

Comment: @Jos could you please add your answer as an actual answer then I can mark it as the actual answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not absolutely sure that you need this package, you can remove it:

```
sudo apt remove dleyna-renderer
sudo apt autoremove
```

Otherwise, there is not much that you can do about this: it is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dleyna-renderer/+bug/1590343).

You could create a launchpad account and add yourself to the number of "people who are affected by this bug" on that page.